# What do I do to make green blood?

Tags: science-based, biology, aliens, xenobiology

Green blood pops up a lot in sci-fi as a type of alien blood. What would be the composition of green blood and how would it effect a lifeform? Would it give the alien race any strengths over Earth-based life?

Comment: Here you go: http://www.compoundchem.com/2014/10/28/coloursofblood/

Comment: Hope you don't mind me marking duplicate. Your answer was already there. +1 anyway because question didn't specifically called for green, and I see how this might make it harder to find.

Comment: @Mołot No that's no problem. Should have checked before posting

Comment: Chlorophyll makes plants green. Humanoid spore/plant creatures? Not really changing blood itself, but still a possible way to have "green blood", if you will.